# How to switch language SugarCE-6.5.11?

Tags: sugarcrm

I wonder how to switch language in Sugar? I have created a new module, wrote 2 language files. And now i want to create 2 radio buttons allow users to choose language.
Any clue will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i take a look at Users module, and in login.php i figure out my answer. After that, i create a view in my module to test it, and here is the result (code in display function). It works fine for me.

```
function display(){
    global $current_language, $mod_strings, $app_strings,$sugar_config;

    echo '
            <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="radio" name="lang" value="en_us" checked="checked">English<br>
            <input type="radio" name="lang" value="vi">Vietnamese<br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form> 
            ';
    if(isset($_POST['lang']))
    {
        $lang = $_POST['lang'];
        $current_language = $lang;

        $_SESSION['authenticated_user_language'] = $lang;
        $mod_strings = return_module_language($lang, "Activity");// Activity is my custom module
        $app_strings = return_application_language($lang);

        SugarApplication::redirect();
    }
}
```